# Setting default NetworkImageView image from XML resource

Tags: android, android-volley

Volley's `NetworkImageView` can be given a default image to show before the actual loading is done in code via `networkImageView.setDefaultImageResId(int)`.

How to do the same from a resource XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way.

In the source file, all of the `NetworkImageView`'s constructors simply call the super constructor (the `ImageView` constructor), thus there is no custom handling of the `AttributeSet` received in the constructor.

If you'd like, you can edit the constructor in the source file and add a piece of code that searches for an XML attribute that sets the default image. It shouldn't be difficult as the default image functionality already exist.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jon-adams/968a3a7325cae9502873 is some simple code that creates a new custom view name MoreNetworkImageView that wraps NetworkImageView but implements loading a few of the custom attributes from XML as per the docs at https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is your simply set the `android:src=""` to the desired drawable. That will then set the initial image. Once volley has fetched the correct image (which you specify in code during run time) it will replace this one.

```
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/listview_item_product_list_imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"           
    android:src="@drawable/loading_image" />
```

Comment: what will happen if image Request failed ??